# save page id in cookies and retrieve that certain id's row from database in other page

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

hi every one i am designing a real estate website i have many ads in my website and when user click on a certain ad it goes to another page "viewmore.php" which gives user more details about that certain ad.  so far i create a 'favorite' or 'save' button on viewmore page that will save the selected page title in a certain page based on cookies for user to read later.
Now i want to send ad's id to the favorite page when ever user click on "add to favotites" thus based on id i can fetch that certain ad data from database . like the page title i want to do this based on cookies.
can i do this? how? this is my current code

```html
//viewmore.php
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
(is_numeric($_GET['ID'])) ? $ID = $_GET['ID'] : $ID = 1;
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE idhome = $ID");
?>
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
(is_numeric($_GET['ID'])) ? $ID = $_GET['ID'] : $ID = 1;
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE idhome = $ID");
?>
<?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result):
$price=$row['price'];
$rent=$row['rent'];
$room=$row['room'];
$date=$row['date'];
?>
<?php 
$cookie_name = "favoritepost";
$cookie_value ="$ID";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<?php 
echo"price";
echo"room";
echo"date";
?>
```

and this is my javascript code which i save page title and page url in cookies after user click on add to favorites

any idea thank u

Comment: please, clarify the question, I can't understant it

Comment: thank you for your answering. forget about the javascript code (second code). as u see in first code i get id, and based on that id i fetch some data from database. my problem is i want to do this process with cookies i mean i want to save this id in cookies and then send it to another page and retrieve it and fetch same data from data base .

Comment: do you want to send a cookie from a php script/page to another one?

Comment: yes, you know as i said in my question i want to add "add to favorites" option to my posts thus when my user click on it the page information goes to another page like "favorites page" thus user can review his or her favorite post every time he wants. and i think if i can send post id and retrieve it i can fetch that certain post data from database

Comment: please, consider that cookies are saved in user's browser. You can set a cookie both client-side (so, on user's browser) and server-side (so, in one of your php file). Also a cookie is readable server-side in the `$_COOKIE` global variable in php (see [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)). So after you set a cookie in a php script, you can simply read it in another script

Comment: you can set a cookie in this way `<?php setcookie("TestCookie", $value); ?>`

Comment: of course I think you should save an array of IDs, so $value should be a php array

Comment: could u please take a look at my first code i edit it now i want to know how can i send it to another page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116966/discussion-between-ddb-and-user6362236).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setcookie()` function must appear BEFORE the `<html>` tag.
After setting it, you can read the cookie every where in your php scripts in this way

```
$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]
```

PS: of course I suppose cookies are enabled on your browser.